# Exporting an extended std::vector dump in MSVS debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, vector

While debugging an issue, I would like to save a copy of a 6000+ sized `std::vector` so I can compare it from run to run.

Now the Microsoft Visual Studio debugger has an 'Immediate Window' where you can dump variables, including `std::vector` by entering a command like

`>Debug.Print m_MyVector`

( there is an alias for this command as a simple `?` )

The problem is, is that it is limited.  Try to dump a long vector and one gets output like
`< More... (The first 100 of 6529 items were displayed.) >`

My problem is how to get the rest.  If it was like the utility `more` and you could get it 100 at a time, that would be OK.  Or if you could set the block to something more than 100 at a time.

While I could write a custom serializer and dump to a file, I don't have `<iostream>` included in this module yet, and I'd hate to start adding things like that just for debugging.

Any other ways to export large data objects out of the MSVS debugger?

Comment: Debug.SaveDumpAs or Debug.ListMemory come to mind

Comment: @stijn I'm not sure how to get the data out of a minidump file, if it is in there.  I apparently don't have `windbg` if that's even the right tool

Comment: making a floating `locals` window and expanding the vector, then right-click `select-all` and `copy` lets me paste into `notepad`.  That looks promising.

Comment: @infixed: You can load up a mini dump file in Visual Studio just as well, but that gets you nowhere closer to your goal. Now you have a post-mortem image of your vector, with no way to dump it to a file, so you're essentially back to square one.

Comment: the dump is indeed a bit too hard, but e.g. `>Debug.ListMemory /signed /count:6000 vec._Myfirst` can achieve roughly the same as the locals window but maybe even faster when combined with `>Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput c:\vec.log` since you'll have the output in a file without neededig to copy/paste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Printing Values Piecemeal in the Immediate Window

> If it was like the utility `more` and you could get it 100 at a time, that would be OK.

You can arrange for this by incrementing the pointer and reprinting. Unfortunately, operator overloads are not available in the Immediate Window, so you can't do something like `?(&m_MyVector[0] + 100)`. Instead, you have to refer to undocumented private members. For example:

```
?(m_MyVector._Myfirst), 100

    ...Prints first 100 items

?(m_MyVector._Myfirst + 100), 100

     ...Prints next 100 items

?(m_MyVector._Myfirst + 200), 100

     ...Prints next 100 items
```

…and so on. The `, 100` syntax there tells it how many items to print. No, asking for more than 100 items doesn't work. You just get the original message:

```
< More... (The first 100 of n items were displayed.) >
```

### Seeing the Big Picture in the Memory Window

Perhaps a better solution would involve the Memory window. This exploits the fact that std::vector is a contiguous container, so all of its elements will be stored adjacent to one another in memory. The Memory window just dumps the contents of memory, which will effectively give you an unlimited dump of the vector's contents.

1. Use the Immediate Window to determine the actual address of the vector's first member:

   ```
   ?m_MyVector._Myfirst
   0x00440068
   ```
2. Make sure that a Memory window is displayed. Debug → Windows → Memory → Memory 1 (there actually are 4 of them; it doesn't matter which one you use). Or just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>.
3. Copy the address you got from the Immediate Window into the top of the Memory window, where it says "Address". Leave the `0x` prefix there, just in case. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. The Memory window will refresh its view to show you the contents of memory at that address, and immediately following it. You can scroll down as far as you like. There is no 100-item limit.

Now, the only disadvantage of this is that the Memory window literally displays a hex dump of bytes. So if you have a vector of strings, you're not going to be nearly as happy as if you have a vector of ints, like I have here (filled sequentially, starting from 0):

[image]

### Dumping to the Clipboard from Auto/Locals Window

The solution you mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246545/exporting-an-extended-stdvector-dump-in-msvs-debugger#comment63915544_38246545) will also work. Use the Autos or Locals window to expand the `m_MyVector` object. Do a Select All, or use Shift+Click at the top and bottom to exclude other unwanted items. Then Copy. If you have a particularly large vector, twiddle your thumbs for a good 30+ seconds while Visual Studio dumps all this data to your clipboard. Then paste into Notepad. After cleaning up the first few lines, you'll have a nice little dump file:

```
std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >
        [size]  60000   unsigned long
        [capacity]  61447   unsigned long
        [0] 0   int
        [1] 1   int
        [2] 2   int
        [3] 3   int
        [4] 4   int
        [5] 5   int
        [6] 6   int
        [7] 7   int
        [8] 8   int
        [9] 9   int
        [10]    10  int
        ...
```